# Efficient way to perform xml parsing in python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have an XML file of(30GB) which contains 2 classes of data, The data of class 1 has corresponding

```
<id="11" class="1" bestmatchingid="50" Body="abc"> </id>
.
.
.
<id="9999890" class="2" MatchingClass1Id="11" Body="xyz"></id>
```

Now the task is to extract class1's body and corresponding class 2's body where e.g.

```
class1's id(11)== MatchingClass1Id of class2(which is 9999890)
```

I am accomplishing the same by using string comparison's in Python...is there a more efficient way in Python to accomplish the same considering my file size is 30 GB

Comment: Why have you tagged regex? XML Parsers are the best way to go...

Comment: I am attempting using regex, therefore tagged regex...but any efficient way would work for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

lxml works good for your purpose. Also since you are a begineer..so for understanding the basic refer to the tutorial:

http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/web/etree-view.html

All iterparse method is an efficient method to solve your problem

Comment: (Completely OT: Hah. I was just to answer the CSV question when you deleted it. I'm surprised at how annoying that was. :-))

Answer (score 4):

Use [LXML](http://lxml.de/)'s `iterparse` function. See the [IBM DeveloperWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/) about it for how to use it on very large files.

Comment: Thanks a ton for helping. Can you please direct me to a tutorial which may help a beginner like me to catch up with the basics of lxml. Also in the IBMDeveloperWorks article...does not work for my code...since i have "id, class, Body, matchingclass1Id " and they guys are working with title...may be since i am novice i did not understand the subtilities...a big apology for disturbing again...but still despite ur helping i m stuck with trying to understand the basics

Comment: @user869790: what exactly is the problem, lack of Python knowledge or lack of XML knowledge?